# How to make effect where emoji fall from the top of view?

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

In my iOS app I would like to make it so that emoji fall from the top of the self.view.

**How can I accomplish this?** [Here is an example of what I mean.](https://monkey.cool/)

Comment: What did you test already ?

Comment: I have made a video and play in the background but it does not have physics effects and generally is bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish a *rain of emoji* style effect, you can use [CAEmitterLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caemitterlayer)

You can configure your position, birthrate, size etc. of your emitterLayer and add it to your view.layer .

Comment: I don't have my system with me but this [link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/calayer/how-to-emit-particles-using-caemitterlayer) should be helpful.